# How can I send AMF Credentials in an AMF request in soapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, amf, loadui

I need to send a login and password with an AMF Request in soapUI.

Yes, I'm aware that there is an option on the testCase level where you can specify this, and that you can set this property through a test step, but I need to send this information with the request without using this method as I am trying to load test this testCase in LoadUI and all Vitual Users seem to use the same AMF session credentials even when I randomize and reset these values in the test run.

Its instantiating every part of the testCase EXCEPT the AMF session credentials, so I need to find a way to send this with script as these are not sent in the request as arguments, is that possible?

Comment: It is possible to set test properties using a Groovy Script is that what you want to do?

Comment: See http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#1-1-get-and-set-properties

Comment: @Rob Kielty  No, I can set these propertis just fine in the Groovy scripts, I'm looking more at trying to CREATE the amf connection and and send the authorization before my AMF Request and Logout and close the connection after the step. For the purposes of my load test, I need to authorize on a step by step basis.

Comment: I see. Have you tried making the AMF connection using a HTTP test step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to manually create the AMF connection and login and logout and close the connection within a Groovy script step.

Found this great blog that explained the whole proccess.

http://aredko.blogspot.com/2010/06/testing-blazeds-remote-objects-with_06.html